# run reduce , map function

Tags: javascript, dictionary

I have 3 classes and data in country.json

country.json

```
[{"country":"Algeria","region":"Northern Africa","code":"DZ","population":41318142,"cities":["Boumerdas","Zeribet el Oued","Zeralda"]},{"country":"American Samoa","region":"Polynesia","code":"AS","population":55641,"cities":["Aūa","Vaitogi","Vailoatai"]}
```

in countryRep class I make this funnction to get the sum of population

```
   async  getSumAllPopulation(){
            let countries = await this.getCountries();
           let populations= countries.map(s=>s.population).reduce((acc, s) => s + acc);
           return populations;
        }
```

in test I write

```
app.get('/PopulationSum', async (req, res) => {
    const countries = await repo.getSumAllPopulation();
    res.send(countries);
})
```

getCountries() function

```
    async getCountries() {
        try {
            const countries = await fs.readJSON(this.countryFilePath);
            return countries;
        }
        catch (e) {
            console.log(e)
        }

    }
```

But I didn't get the result of the sum ? How I can fix it? I got an error it seems the method didn't return any thing.

[image]

Comment: It is maybe because you forgot to run reduce with an initial value: `reduce((acc, s) => s + acc, 0)`

Comment: same problem, I try it before.

Comment: @MorKadosh Default is 0

Comment: What is the error you get? Post that in the question

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava just learned something new. :)

Comment: The code itself related to `.map()` and `.reduce()` looks good to me. What do you have in `getCountries` function? How do you resolve the `Promise` inside? From the error it seems an error occurred there.

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava you can check it , I post the error

Comment: @norbitrial I post the function

Comment: Issue is that you send a number in res.send, which is interpreted as a response code, use string or object

Comment: @norbitrial Its work yes . thank you

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava yah I solve it. thank you